# angular ng-repeat searching specific fields only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This must be very common however ive been unable to find an answer (so i am hoping you guys can help)

For the purpose of this question i have created the following fiddle:

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.$"/>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in tableData |filter:search">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.street}}</td>
        <td>{{item.number}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.tableData = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.tableData.push({
      id: i,
      name: generateRandomName(),
      street: generateRandomName(),
      number: generateRandomNumber()
    })
  }

  function generateRandomName() {
    var length = 4;
    var charset = "abcdefghjknpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
      retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }

    return retVal;
  }

  function generateRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
}
```

Fiddle can be found here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9595/)

Now let me explain the issue.

As you can see the object consists of four fields in this case: `id,name,street,number`

However in our table we are not showing the field `id`

We have added all of these objects to our `tableData` array. in order to filter / search our table we have created an input field:

```
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.$"/>
```

Notice the `ng-model="search.$"` Now with this single text input we wish to search the table. However something is strange (from the user's perspective):

[image]

We search for the number 95 however a result displays that seems to be not connected with our search.

Problem is that `search.$` searches the full object even if the values are not displayed in the table. The result showed in the picture above is actually the `id field` of the object that has been found. Since the maximum street number is 10 any search for a number above 10 would result in incorrect results.

So my question is how can you fix this? how can you with a single text input limit search to specific fields in the object?

Comment: choices would be use custom filter or remove id from each object which probably isn't practical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your search variable inside controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {

 $scope.search = "";

  $scope.tableData = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.tableData.push({
      id: i,
      name: generateRandomName(),
      street: generateRandomName(),
      number: generateRandomNumber()
    })
  }

  function generateRandomName() {
    var length = 4;
    var charset = "abcdefghjknpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
      retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }

    return retVal;
  }

  function generateRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }


}
```

And Filter based on the search value,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter:{name:search}">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.street}}</td>
        <td>{{item.number}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: would this work for the other values or only for name? is it possible to do filter:{name: search, street: search, number:search} ?

Comment: yes, but that will return data's that matches all the three columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need define own `comparator`:

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

see [filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/api/ng/filter/filter)